# aspxgridview header filter multi select from column content

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm using aspxgridview in my project and i have a language column as seen above. Each row is for a product. First product has 2 languages, second has 4 and 3rd has 3 languages... In product table i record languages in a single cell for each product like ,2,3,4, (these ara language table ids) and i am showing them in the grid like above with language codes and seperating them with dash... I could't able to find multiple select for this issue... I mean i want to search TK and TH language code used products from multi select dropdown..

[image: www.yazilimakademi.com/1.jpg]

when i select TK and TH

[image]

no data to display...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default it is only returning the first item you selected.  You will need to write some code to include each item selected as well as the character you use to seperate the values.  I found a good example [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E2203.aspx)